# Generating random URL in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I wish to see if it is possible to generate a random link each time an admin visits the admin page.

for example: instead of having: `"".com/admin`, there would be `"".com/a93k`, `"".com/9dik`. The page stays the same but just so the end-user can't access the page from the address bar.

Thanks as I am new and do not know how I can implement this.

Comment: Instead of having this as a page reference, why don't you try passing a parameter, something like `blabla.com?par=a93k`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In .config of your app put something like

```
window.adminHash = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2,6);
```

In your routing

```
url: '/' + window.adminHash
```

Then you can use "window.adminHash" if you want to redirect to your route, which will change every time you refresh the page

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

You can add www.test-example.com/admin/{provide some ID}

And If there isn't ID provide discard that URL, if it is provided you can make discrimination.